# import react function component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Im trying to do some basic importing of a react function component to the main App.js

but for some reason it’s just not importing

can someone help me understand, why it’s not importing my component?

this is the App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import mainGrid from './components/mainGrid';


function App() {
  return (
    <mainGrid/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is the mainGrid.js

```js
import React from "react";
import "./mainGrid.css";

 function mainGrid() {
    return (
      <div className="mainGrid">
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
        <div class="grid-box"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default mainGrid;
```

Comment: Make sure to use .jsx for react components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capitalize the react element name.

As per [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type):

> Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MainGrid from './components/mainGrid';


function App() {
  return (
    <MainGrid />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: nice i knew it has something small, but I just couldn’t remember what is the problem,

Comment: I didn’t code for like the last 8 months so some stuff I forgot, thank you 